# Inline assembler constraints not met in timing loop on AVR XMEGA with avr-gcc

Tags: c, embedded, inline-assembly, avr

I'm having a problem with a millisecond-delay loop in AVR-targeted C. I am using `avr-gcc 4.7.0` on Linux which I got from Ubuntu repos, and I have also tried a freshly compiled 4.7.2. The target hardware is an XMEGA128A1, clocked at 2 MHz for now.

The following function often (but not always - I had used a few calls to this function before running into trouble) complains about the constraints:

```
../common/spin_delay.h:64:9: warning: asm operand 3 probably doesn’t match constraints [enabled by default]
../common/spin_delay.h:64:9: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’
```

It will also complain about operands 0, 1 and 2 if I remove the particular call which stops compilation with this error.

```c
#define LOOPS_PER_MS ((CPU_CLK_HZ/1000)/4)

static inline void ms_spin(unsigned short ms) {
    if (ms) {
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "   ldi r24, %1     \n"
            "   ldi r25, %0     \n"
            "1: ldi r26, %3     \n"
            "    ldi r27, %2    \n"
            "2: sbiw r26, 1     \n"
            "    brne 2b        \n"
            "    sbiw r24, 1    \n"
            "    brne 1b        \n"
            : 
            : "M" (ms >> 8), 
              "M" (ms & 0xff),
              "M" (LOOPS_PER_MS >> 8), 
              "M" (LOOPS_PER_MS & 0xff)
            : "r24", "r25", "r26", "r27"
        );
    }
}
```

The same code compiles just fine on Windows with `avr-gcc 4.3.3` from WinAVR, however, which makes me think it's some change in the inline assembler since then.

To my mind, it all looks correct, as the 16-bit short is decomposed into the high byte and low byte and constrained by "M" (8-bit constant), while the fact that it worked a few times rules out problems with the hard-defined `CPU_CLK_HZ`-derived constants. The fact that the problem operand is any of 0-3 implies it's not a particular asm operand that's failing.

I did also try to use the `n` constraint as recommended [here](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=printview&t=124432&start=0), but the error persisted.

Comment: It would be simpler and more elegant to use a hardware timer, and easier to manage different clock frequencies.  You could poll using C rather than assembler and still be sure that it would not vary with compiler optimisation (which I assume id you reason for using assembler). Also because the timer runs independently you can do something useful while you are waiting rather than just spinning.

Comment: @Clifford - this is true, and I did get a busy-wait working with one of the hardware timers on the XMEGA. This wasn't really in a place where I wanted to add in the infrastructure to wander off and do something else before coming back to check the timer, so I didn't use an interrupt.

Comment: In many cases it does not need an interrupt, but rather to simply "do work" in the wait loop - so long as the subsequent loop time and determinism meets your application's real-time requirements.  Beyond that the "obvious" infrastructure to deploy would be an RTOS. Either way, so long as you hadn't missed a trick, and this implementation is an informed decision, that was my only concern really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Edit:

Recent gcc versions support a built-in for cycle-accurate delays:

[`void __builtin_avr_delay_cycles (unsigned long ticks)`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/gcc/AVR-Built_002din-Functions.html)

(Note though: "ticks must be a compile time integer constant; delays with a variable number of cycles are not supported.")

---

I assume the problem lies within your declaration of the `ms` variable as a *constant* input to your assembler. I believe, this should not even compile in the first place.

If and when it does compile, it would probably be only because of compiler optimizations which make gcc 'recognize' that what is declared as a variable (`ms`) is actually constant and known at compile-time. Yet, these optimizations cannot be relied upon to always happen in the same way.

My recommendation is thus *not* to use the `"M"` constraint for `ms`, as it's basically out-of-place here.

You will probably get more robust and correct code, maybe even more performant, by using the 'correct' constraints, as in:

```
#define LOOPS_PER_MS (((CPU_CLK_HZ/1000)-(1+1+2+2))/(2+2)) // accounting for the overhead of 6 (1+1+2+2) cycles per ms and the 4 (2+2) cycles per inner loop iteration

static inline void ms_spin(unsigned short ms) {
    if (ms) {
        unsigned short dummy;
        __asm__ __volatile__ (
            "ms_spin_outer_loop_%=:                \n"

            "    ldi %A[loopcnt], lo8(%[loops])    \n"
            "    ldi %B[loopcnt], hi8(%[loops])    \n"

            "ms_spin_inner_loop_%=:                \n"

            "    sbiw %A[loopcnt], 1               \n"
            "    brne ms_spin_inner_loop_%=        \n"

            "    sbiw %A[ms], 1                    \n"
            "    brne ms_spin_outer_loop_%=        \n"

            :  [ms] "+w" (ms),
               [loopcnt] "=&w" (dummy)
            :  [loops] "i" (LOOPS_PER_MS)
            :  // none.
        );
    }
}
```

Using the 'correct' constraints also leaves the selection of the particular register set to use to the gcc which may result in better optimizations around your inline assembler statements.

To make things even more predictable, you may want to consider forcing gcc to *always* inline the function via the `__attribute__((always_inline))` decoration.

For more details on the inline assembler constraints in avr-gcc see for example the [avr-libc documentation](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/inline_asm.html#io_ops). This list is not exhaustive, so a look at the general [gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html) may prove helpful from time to time.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes a lot more sense now! One thing I had to change was `lo8(loops)` to `lo8(%[loops])` to avoid a `undefined reference to 'loops'` link error.